# OpenLayers feature styling change by the baselayer

Tags: openlayers-2, feature-layer

How can I have the style of the features on a vector layer depending on the OpenLayers' "base layer"?

For example, some base layers are dark images and I need (for the contrast) the features to be displayed bright in the vector layer upon the base layer. And as soon as base layer changes to a bright one, features should be redrawn dark.

How can I achieve this with OpenLayers code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a Stylemap and a context function.

This example shows it in operation http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/styles-context.html

Your function would return the value based upon the features layer, eg:-

```
var context = {
            getColor: function(feature) {
                var baselayer = feature.map.baseLayer;

                ... 

                SELECT and return your color based upon the baselayer 
                ...
            }
        };
```

Comment: What actually worked was `feature.layer.map.baseLayer.name.toString()` for selection based upon the baselayer name